# Could not load type "Symfony\Component\Form\SubmitButton"

Tags: symfony, symfony-3.2

hey i have my form and then an errour shows me i did my controller and path right 
 /*

```
namespace DataBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\SubmitButton;
```

//Ive  got my use
    use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

```
class VoitureType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('immatricule')->add('marque')->add('modele')->add('typecarburant')->add('nbcheveaux')->add('datemarche')->add('nbrPlace')
            ->add('Ajouter',SubmitButton::class) ;
```

//it seems like here is the error

```
//thats for my car entity 
        ;
    }

*/
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't use SubmitButton as a type.
The right type is SubmitType

```
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;
// ...
->add('Ajouter',SubmitType::class);
```

By the way, Symfony consider as a best practice to not put the submit button in the form class.

> **Best Practice**
>
> Add buttons in the templates, not in the form classes or the controllers.

[Form Button Configuration](http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/forms.html#form-button-configuration)